# Error when adding a member to a group: "Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_members to add a member to a group

```
POST /groups/{id}/members/$ref
{
"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx@yyy.com"
}
```

returns error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service."
    }
}
```

The group that I'm trying to add to has the following properties:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
    "id": "xxx",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "classification": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2017-09-11T21:04:49Z",
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "xxx",
    "groupTypes": [],
    "mail": "xxx@yyy.com",
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "xxx",
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "preferredDataLocation": null,
    "proxyAddresses": [
        "smtp:xxx@yyy.com",
        "SMTP:xxx@yyy.com"
    ],
    "renewedDateTime": "2017-09-11T21:04:49Z",
    "securityEnabled": false,
    "visibility": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the reason for the rejection was because Microsoft only allows adding members to Office 365 Groups (groupTypes = ["Unified"])

In my case, the group properties above shows (groupTypes= [])

Answer (score 0):

My test result for your reference.
[image]

List user ID so get user ID.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```